# How to Bypass Adblocker Interference with GTM gtag.js Download on Custom Subdomain

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm currently facing a challenge with my website's tracking setup and would appreciate any insights or solutions. Here's a brief overview of my situation:

Setup: I am using Google Tag Manager (GTM) on both the server side and client side. For the server side, I have a custom subdomain set up.

Initial Success: I've managed to download the gtm.js file successfully without it being blocked by adblockers.

The Issue: The problem arises after gtm.js is downloaded. It attempts to make an API call to my subdomain to fetch gtag.js. Unfortunately, this call is being blocked by some adblockers.

While I ensure not to track any sensitive data, tracking is crucial for my business operations.

I am looking for advice or techniques to circumvent this adblocker issue, allowing gtag.js to be downloaded without violating any privacy norms. Any suggestions or guidance on how to address this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!